# Distinct Bacula FileSet options per directory

Tags: bacula

Let's say I have a Bacula FileSet containing:

```
Include {
    Options {
        checkfilechanges=yes
        onefs = yes
        # and other irrelevant options here
    }
    File = /
}
```

Generally I think having checkfilechanges=yes is a good thing, but for /var/log and everything below I consider it a nuisance.  Is there a way I can turn it off for that while leaving it on for everything else when they're both from the same filesystem?

It would seem that I'd need to exclude /var/log with the above and then use another Include with differing options just for /var/log in an contradictory way that makes me nervous and to the best of my knowledge, undocumented.  I certainly could achieve this with two separate FileSets, but then that means two Jobs, multiply that by the number of clients I have and ick.